# Substituting nodes for paths from root in jq

Tags: arrays, json, path, jq

How do I substitute a certain matching node in a tree by the path to that node from the root node using jq?

Using `walk`, only the path from the current node downwards the tree is accessible:

https://jqplay.org/s/BVOQ-xa1JM:

```
walk(if type == "object" and has("d") then .d = path(.) else . end)
```

Input:

```
{"a": {"b": 1, "c": {"d": 2}}, "e": {"d}
```

Result:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": 1,
    "c": {
      "d": []
    }
  },
  "e": {
    "d": []
  }
}
```

The desired result is:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": 1,
    "c": {
      "d": ["a", "c"]
    }
  },
  "e": {
    "d": ["e"]
  }
}
```

Note: this must not cause duplication of the full tree as in:

```
(paths | select(.[-1] == "d")) as $f | setpath($f; $f[:-1])
```

Which causes:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": 1,
    "c": {
      "d": [
        "a",
        "c"
      ]
    }
  },
  "e": {
    "d": 3
  }
}
{
  "a": {
    "b": 1,
    "c": {
      "d": 2
    }
  },
  "e": {
    "d": [
      "e"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I've corrected the example result to result in `["a","c"]` for the path from root to `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected output is not correct as `b` is not involved int he downward path of `d` from root. You can use the `paths` functions involving `setpath()` in `--null-input` mode i.e. with `jq -n`

```
( inputs | paths | select(.[-1] == "d")) as $f | setpath($f; $f[:-1])
```

The idea is to construct the path lane upto `d` in a variable `$f` and use the set path function to set value on the same. The part `[:-1]` trims the last entry in the array leaving the leaf node.

[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/N1f8LQp1eg)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a complete solution: is causes duplication of the full tree for more than one case of `d`. Check my edited question.